# PagingScroller in ExtJs 4.1 MVC grid implementation not triggering ajax request

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc, infinite-scroll, extjs4.1

I am trying to figure out a basic implementation of infinite scrolling in a ExtJs 4.1.0 grid.

I am working off this example http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-1-grid-infinite-scroll-in-mvc and at this point my code is practically identical to the example.

When my page loads, the grid is filled with the first page of data as the first ajax request fires and works as expected.  However, when I scroll down to the bottom of the grid, nothing happens...  I am expecting to see an ajax request fire, grabbing additional data (as in the example).

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./extjs-4.1.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./extjs-4.1.0/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./test-scrolling.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
                <div class='wrap'>
                     <h1>Test</h1>

                    <div class='clear'></div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div id="main"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
Ext.define('AP.model.Log', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'Id',
        'ProcessId',
        'IndexRequest',
        'AssetIndexStart',
        'AssetIndexEnd',
        'StartDate',
        'EndDate']
});

Ext.define('AP.store.Log', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AP.model.Log',
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost/...',
        limitParam: 'limit',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Log',
            successProperty: 'Success'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('AP.view.Log', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.log',
    title: 'Log',
    store: 'Log',
    initComponent: function () {
        this.columns = [{
            header: 'Index Start',
            dataIndex: 'AssetIndexStart',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            header: 'Index End',
            dataIndex: 'AssetIndexEnd'
        }, {
            header: 'Start Date',
            dataIndex: 'StartDate'
        }, {
            header: 'End Date',
            dataIndex: 'EndDate'
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('AP.controller.Log', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Log'],
    models: ['Log'],
    views: ['Log'],
    init: function () {}
});

Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'AP',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: [
        'Log'],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.widget('log', {
            title: 'Log',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            renderTo: 'main'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same version (4.1.0 FINAL) as the linked example? Work was done on the infinite scroll grid throughout the the 4.1 beta and RC stages

Comment: I downloaded it from Sencha a few days ago, was the final version for sure.  I have also tried with <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>